# Как сделать скрин страницы?

Tags: python

есть 400 ссылок формата

https://vk.com/wall651046594_2

Нужно через requests пройти по каждой пердавая куки и заголовик и сделать снимок экрана. апи других сервисов не подходят, они не передают куки и вк пишет что юзер не авторизован

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org) и [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev). На них возможно делать снимки экрана. Как-либо иначе рендерить html будет довольно сложно.